# How do I turn a list of times in a list into seconds in pandas/jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

How do I turn a list of times in a list into seconds? Each completed package signifies one string. I want to calculate the difference of the first time to the second time, second time to third time so forth. I've included a copy and paste of my code but i got a type error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' at diff = romulus[i-1] - romulus[i]

```
# The timestamps of completed packages are saved as strings in a list for each machine

romulus = ['2021/12/01 08:03:53', '2021/12/01 08:07:28', '2021/12/01 08:11:57', '2021/12/01 08:14:01', '2021/12/01 08:16:43']


def get_rom(romulus):
    rom_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(romulus)):
        diff = romulus[i-1] - romulus[i] 
        
        diff_in_seconds = diff.total_seconds
        
        rom_list.append(diff_in_seconds)
        
    return rom_list

print(get_rom(romulus))
```

Comment: Minor: I believe you would have this problem with your code if you were running this in Python on the console/interpreter, too, & so 'Jupyter notebook' doesn't really belong in the title of the post or in the topics tags, but 'Python' does. It is always good to mention where you are running your Python in the post in case that is involved. However, usually you can run your code in the console/interpreter or as a script to rule out Jupyter's involvement. In time you'll probably get a feel for it & it will help you in knowing where to look for related help to keep the domains clear in your head.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are almost there, you need to convert the time strings in romulus to proper datetime objects and then find the differences and output the difference in seconds.  Here is how to update your code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_rom(romulus):
    rom_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(romulus)):
        diff = datetime.strptime(romulus[i-1], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(romulus[i], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') 
        
        diff_in_seconds = diff.seconds
        
        rom_list.append(diff_in_seconds)
        
    return rom_list
```

Then ```get_rom(romulus)

```
[770, 86185, 86131, 86276, 86238]
```

A more succinct approach using list comprehension would look like:

```
def get_diff_in_seconds(rl: list[str]) -> list[int]:
    diff = [(datetime.strptime(rl[x-1], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(rl[x], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')) for x in range(1, len(rl)) ]
    return [x.seconds for x in diff]
```